# SDKs or Commandline Tools to Convert DOC and TIFF to PDF in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, pdf-conversion

I've been working on a project that converts several file formats to a PDF in VB.NET/C#. The specific files are DOC, TXT, JPG, TIFF, HTML.

Actually I already have a solution for **DOC/TXT to PDF** using Bullzip PDF Printer by sending the files to the PDF Printer using VB.NET. However, each time it converts a file, MS Word opens and then closes once the file is sent to the printer. It really slows down the process.

As for **TIFF to PDF**, I haven't found a solution for it at this time.

I require SDKs or Commandline tools and not PDF convertion applications, since I need to integrate this function in my program. I prefer free or open source SDKs but commercial ones are accepted as well.

If anyone could point me to the right direction regarding this matter that would be much appreciated. I would also like to point out that I have done some research on this matter but I haven't found the right one yet.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are quite a few duplicates of this question that have already been asked here on Stack Overflow. Check the "Related" sidebar at the right of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you seen either [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) or [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)?**
Both are open-source libraries for working with PDF files that work very well with .NET applications.

[Aspose.Pdf](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) is another option, if you're open to commercial software.

Comment: Hi Cody. Yes I have used iTextSharp and PDFSharp in this project. Mainly for the output PDF manipulation (adding text etc). Can you show me how to use this to convert DOC to PDF? Thanks.

Comment: You can't.  As far as format conversion goes, iText only supports HTML->PDF.